# How to change default widge styles?

Tags: django, django-templates

I add field like 
forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=OPTIONS, initial=0)
when display, the normal dropdown is replaced with one with a search box on item list, I think that is Django widget?

I had to add the style to set wdith, otherwise, the dropdown will show with width 33px, way too small

But then I need embed those dropdowns into a jquery accordion. I found dropdowns in non-active section will all have width set to 0px.  I guess widget set it to 0 after it detects them are hidden.

From A you can tell the dropdown has styles to make it have round corners
[image: A]
From B, you can see the dropdown doesn't show anything, from the html code, I see the width is set to 0px
[image: B]
If I don't apply the accordion, you see all three dropdowns are fine
[image: C]
I am looking for a way to solve this, either make widget not set width that way, or remove widget effect at all.

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: `django-crispy-forms` takes a lot of the hassle out of custom form rendering.

Comment: The site is on live already, I am looking for a way to solve it but doesn't change others much

Comment: Are you talking about Django Admin or a custom site? Could you post html/css of a generated form (might be screen from dev tools)?

Comment: thanks, screenshots added